# Why can't successfully initialize python MetaTrader5

Tags: python, metatrader5

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5

  # display data on the MetaTrader 5 package
 print("MetaTrader5 package author: ", mt5.__author__) 
print("MetaTrader5 package version: ", mt5.__version__)  

# establish connection to the MetaTrader 5 terminal

 if not mt5.initialize(path="C:\\Program Files\\FTMO MetaTrader 5\\terminal64.exe",server="FTMO-Server",login=mylogin, password="mypass"):     
        print("initialize() failed, error code =",mt5.last_error())     
        quit() 
else:     
        print("initialized success!")
```

I have tried turning off firewall, restarting server, update to latest MetaTrader5 python module with no avail.

It's a simple script to test a connection and it just won't work. Can it be the broker blocking it?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies on

Within the MT5 platform, under tools/options there is a tab called "Community" where one has to enable "Python Integration"

This is nowhere to be found in the documentation!